# Is there a free API for hotel search?

Tags: api, http, rest

I would like to create a web application for my thesis in university. It's a simple app that has a few input fields, like "city", "start date", and "end date". With these information I would like to get the hotels in the given city with http rest calls to the API. I searched on google for good free APIs that I can work with, but found none. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first (and usually last) stop when looking for an API is programmableweb.com

They list lots of hotel related APIs, but a quick search for "travelocity api" turned up theirs as well http://connect.lastminute.com/Developer .  Other bookings sites may have their own available, but it was available via a quick search (duckduckgo vs. google but still....)